# Model not saving values to history model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save to an history table (`configs_histories`) all the values inside the `configs` table everytime a user edits or creates a new Config. So I use the callback `after_save` inside my `Config` model to call the `save_configs_map_to_history` function.
However, when I edit a config, rails fails to save the values in the history table, showing `rollback transaction` in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Please help, thanks in advance!

**config.rb:**

```
class Config < ApplicationRecord  

  after_save :save_configs_map_to_history

  belongs_to :mirth

  has_paper_trail

  def save_configs_map_to_history

    configs = Config.all

    version_no = (ConfigsHistory.maximum('version') || 0) + 1

    configs.each do |config|

      ConfigsHistory.create!(key: config.key, value: config.value,
                             comment: config.comment, mirth_id: config.mirth_id,
                             version: version_no, config_created_at: config.created_at,
                             config_updated_at: config.updated_at, config_created_by: config.created_by,
                             config_updated_by: config.updated_by)

    end

  end

end
```

**part of my console log:**

```
...
(0.0ms)  SELECT MAX("configs_histories"."version") FROM "configs_histories"
    Config Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "configs".* FROM "configs"
    Mirth Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "mirths".* FROM "mirths" WHERE "mirths"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    (27.0ms)  rollback transaction
    Rendering configs/_edit.html.erb within layouts/application
...
```

**configs_history.rb:**

```
class ConfigsHistory < ApplicationRecord  

 belongs_to :mirth
 belongs_to :user

end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add gem 'pry-rails' to your gemfile and run bundle
2. Restart your server

In your code

```
class Config < ApplicationRecord  

  after_save :save_configs_map_to_history

  belongs_to :mirth

  has_paper_trail

  def save_configs_map_to_history

    configs = Config.all

    version_no = (ConfigsHistory.maximum('version') || 0) + 1

    configs.each do |config|

    binding.pry
      config_history = ConfigsHistory.create!(key: config.key, value: config.value,
                             comment: config.comment, mirth_id: config.mirth_id,
                             version: version_no, config_created_at: config.created_at,
                             config_updated_at: config.updated_at, config_created_by: config.created_by,
                             config_updated_by: config.updated_by)

    end

  end

end
```

When you run your code check your rails console, it will halt and you will get a console to debug the problem.

In that window copy your next line and you will see it fail.

After that just do config_history.errors and see the errors messages.

That should give you enough info to debug your situation and resolve your errors.

To know how to use pry check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A494WFSi6HU

Comment: Thanks! gonna give it a try :)

Comment: I've tried to use pry but it doesn't work with RubyMine. I'm using Rubymine as my IDE. Guess I need to find the error in another way. I tried to debug using the IDE, but I can't still find the problem :(

Comment: I managed to use pry in Bash. When I run config_history it answers with "nil". So, doing config_history.errors just gives "undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass". I can't understand why it is nill.

Comment: What did you mean when you said: "In that window copy your next line and you will see it fail." ? Copy what next line?

Comment: Hey wait a min.. After paying a little bit more attention.. You want to save all the configs to the config_history model? OR that particular config which you created or edited?

Comment: also could you paste the contents of the ConfigHistory.rb in your question?

Comment: Yes, I want to save all the configs to the config_history model. But I found the problem! It was missing a mandatory field (user_id) in the create and it failed to save the value, but the error was not shown. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It was missing a mandatory field (`user_id`) in the `ConfigsHistory.create` and it failed to save the value, but the error was not shown (need to find a way to output those kind of errors). Thanks for your time and suggestions!